# SDL 2.0 Error In Orwell C++

Tags: c++, compilation, sdl, mingw32

I have tried looking for an answer, but can't find much on SDL. Im trying to create a simple window, and the compiler is giving this error:

```
E:\Dev-C++\Project1\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

It also highlights this line in the Makefile:

```
$(BIN): $(OBJ)
$(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o $(BIN) $(LIBS)
```

Not sure how to fix, ive added the directories and the inludes:

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

Ive seen the `#include "SDL2/SDL.h"` but it appears to be an older version of SDL then I am using.

Also I am using MinGW32.
Any suggestions / Help?

Comment: `ld returned 1 exit status` - it is linker error, not compiler. It failed to find library, not header file.

Comment: Sorry but im new to this, how would one go about to fix this?

Comment: You should add 'sdl' library to somewhere like project -> linker settings. SDL is not standard library, so you have to add this library manually. SDL 1.x requires 'sdl.lib' to be included to the library list

Comment: Ok I tried switching a few things around, it fixed that error. I believe that I had the 32bit and 64bit libs switched around. In the tutorial it said to add :-lmingw32 -lSDLmain  to the linker, which I did, but it said it is unable to find it. If I take it out, it gives 300 errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Is the name of the library file is sdlmain.lib? 2. Is sdlmain.lib located in any standard library folder of MINGW?

Comment: Interesting, I searched the SDL library then the MinGW lib, and then searched my whole computer. There is no file with the name sdlmain.lib. There is a libSDL2.a?

Comment: Yeah, you are quite right - it is libSDL2.a. And, as I remember, mingw wants a name without heading 'lib' and tailing '.a'.

Comment: If you use SDL2, you should include "SDL2/SDL.h" and link with `-lSDL2 -lSDL2main` (last one makes sense only on windows, should be omitted for other OSes).